# Mostrar en Angular, un Json que recibo de Api ó servicio tipo Get

Tags: angular, json, api, get

Esta es la documentación del api que necesito consumir y pintar en el html, es un servicio GET:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el contenido de mi servicio donde tengo la url del api que quiero consumir:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el contenido de mi archivo ts:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, ya que no tengo idea como pintar esa información en el html
Gracias.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo practicamente ya tienes lo más díficil, sólo te falta mapear tú response en un modelo por ejemplo

```
export interface MiResponse { id: number, name: string};
```

Luego retornarlo en tú llamado al API como un Observable de la sig. manera:

```
public getAll(): Observable<MiResponse> {
    return this.http.get<MiResponse>(url);
  }
```

En tu componente ya tienes el servicio inyectado, y el llamado al método, sólo te falta mapearlo en una property:

```
public response: Observable<MiResponse> = new Observable();
```

Y en tu onInit:

```
this._pokeService
       .getAll()
       .subscribe((data) => {
         this.response = data;
       });
```

Y en tú HTML sólo lo pintas con interpólación {{}}:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <mi-component>
    {{response.name}}
    </mi-component>
</div>
```